# html javascript expand <details> on mouseover and collapse on mouseout

Tags: javascript, html

[`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) HTML element is collapsed by default and is expanded on mouse click. I am trying to override the default behavior so that it will be expanded on [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) and collapsed on [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event).

I would like to collapse only when the mouse is out of the both the internal details and the summary. How can it be achieved?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const details = document.body.querySelectorAll("details");
  for (const detail of details) {
    detail.addEventListener("mouseover", (evt) => {
      console.log(evt.target.parentElement.setAttribute("open", true));
    });
    detail.addEventListener("mouseout", (evt) => {
      console.log(evt.target.parentElement.removeAttribute("open"));
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>summary</summary>
  internal details
</details>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`. The later events bubble, so when you `mouseout` the `<summary>`, the event listener fires, but really, you'd only want the event listener to fire on the mouse leaving the `<details>` itself.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const details = document.body.querySelectorAll("details");
  for (const detail of details) {
    detail.addEventListener("mouseenter", (evt) => {
      console.log(evt.target.setAttribute("open", true));
    });
    detail.addEventListener("mouseleave", (evt) => {
      console.log(evt.target.removeAttribute("open"));
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>summary</summary>
  internal details
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can wrap the "internal details" with a <div> tag and it should work, no need to change the original script.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const details = document.body.querySelectorAll("details");
  for (const detail of details) {
    detail.addEventListener("mouseover", (evt) => {
      console.log(evt.target.parentElement.setAttribute("open", true));
    });
    detail.addEventListener("mouseout", (evt) => {
      console.log(evt.target.parentElement.removeAttribute("open"));
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>summary</summary>
  <div>
    internal details
  </div>
</details>
```